# Execute code when pressing button created programmatically in function

Tags: swift, function, uibutton

I have created a custom Alert View with buttons that are created dynamically.

Everything works fine except I don't know how to make each button do something different.

**What I mean by that is that I call a function `addButton` and I pass a block of code (like in `UIAlertAction()`). I want that code to execute after I press the button but it actually gets executed when the button is loaded.**

Sorry if I'm unclear but I don't know the specific terms about my issue. Basically I tried to reproduce `UIAlertView` and I don't know how to fully remake `UIAlertAction`.

Here's the method (note: it's in a custom class):

```
func addButton(buttonNumber number: Int, title: String, color: UIColor, actions: () -> Void ) {
    // Initialization
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5, self.wrapper.bounds.height-CGFloat(55*number), self.wrapper.bounds.width-10, 50))
    // Configuration
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = color
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myCustomView.buttonPressed(actions:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    wrapper.addSubview(button)
}
```

This is the selector (I know it's not correct):

```
func buttonPressed(actions actions: () -> Void) {
    actions() // How do I get the actions from addButton?
}
```

And this is when I call `addButton`:

```
        let alertView = UIStoryboard(name: "Popups", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HAlertView") as! HAlertViewVC
        prepareAlert(alertView)

        alertView.loadAlert(title: "Hold on", message: "You need to add at least the goal before saving", image: "Warning-Icon", numberOfActions: 1)

        alertView.addButton(buttonNumber: 1, title: "Close", color: UIColor(red: 246.0/255.0, green: 71.0/255.0, blue: 71.0/255.0, alpha: 1), actions: { 
    //        alertView.dismiss() // This is the problem. That's just a function that hides the alert view but the issue is that it gets executed right away.
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are closures:

```
  var some_code_block = {
      print("my awesome code block!")
  }
```

Put this at a higher / global scope, then you can run / change the block at will, simply by adding '()' at the end of the closure (variable name)

```
 func addCode() {
     // Wont execute:
     some_code_block = { print("new code inserted") }
 }

 func buttonPressed() {
     // Executes: 
     some_code_block()
 }
```

Personally, I use arrays / dictionaries to store / update code blocks on the fly.. then you can iterate through / match indices/keys to get the code block you want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

If your problem is actually *making different buttons*, then you can store your newly created instance of a UI button into an array or dictionary

`[UIButton]`

An array / dictionary of buttons, matching with an array / dictionary of code blocks can certainly work... You just have to make sure they are in the right scope / and synchronize indices / keys.

Or, you could create a class / struct that holds a UIButton instance, and a code block, then put the class / struct into an array / dictionary

```
// Make your own initializer for your purposes
struct ButtonStuff {
    var button: UIButton?
    var code_block: ()?
}

// Make empty array that holds type ButtonStuff (global / outer scope)
var buttons: [ButtonStuff] = [] 

func addButton(pram1:Pram1, pram2:Pram2) {
    // Make a new button (called locally inside of a func)
    var new_button = ButtonStuff()

    // Put stuff in here...
    // new_button.button = pram1
    // new_button.code_block = pram2

    // Add our locally made new_button to the Global buttons array
    buttons.append(new_buttons)
}
```

NOTE: The pram1, pram2 can be whatever you want, but to store to the code block (without running it) you want type `()`. If you want to automatically run the code block, you would use type `()->()`

There are many ways of doing the above (you don't have to use optionals); just a quick example. You would then just have to make some logic / algo to find the right button, display it, then call the code block.

If you have any questions, need me to edit my answer, please leave a message in the comments with @fluidity

Comment: NP!! im still new myself. glad I could help